# How to make the select_tag keep value of last search?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a dropdown of prices using a select_tag, but each time I use the dropdown to set a price and then do the search then the values in the dropdowns go back to their default value when the search results are returned. How do I make the dropdown stay at the last value? Here's the code, I've got the :selected => at the end but don't know what value to give it:

```
<%= label :price, 'max', "to $" %>
<%= select_tag(:max, options_for_select([['$100,000', 100000], ['$200,000', 200000], ...['$20,000,000', 20000000]], :selected => ['$1,000,000', 1000000])) %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:selected` should point to the last element of the array element that you want to pre select.

Try

`<%= select_tag(:max, options_for_select([['$100,000', 100000], ['$200,000', 200000], ...['$20,000,000', 20000000]], :selected => 1000000)) %>`

If you want to keep the value from your current request you may go for

`<%= select_tag(:max, options_for_select([['$100,000', 100000], ['$200,000', 200000], ...['$20,000,000', 20000000]], :selected => params[:max])) %>`

See [options_for_select on the Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select) as well.

Comment: I works in rails 5, just be careful to insert `selected` inside the `options_for_select` function and not outside.