# rails make select tag remember selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form with select

```
<%= form_tag "?", :method => :get, :class => "form-inline" do %>
<%=select_tag 'brand_name', options_for_select(@brands.collect{ |b| [b.name, b.name] })%>

    <button class="btn btn-default " type="submit" value ="search">apply </button>
<%end%>
```

It seems to be working.
So I want to include blank option with text `select brand`
I tried this:

`<%=select_tag 'brand_name', options_for_select(@brands.collect{ |b| [b.name, b.name] }), {:include_blank => 'select brand'}%>`

But now This blank option is always selected.
For example If I select `coca-cola` and press submit button 
I go to the page `mysite?brand_name=coca-cola`
But the selected option in my dropdown blank (`select brand`)
So how can I make it select option `coca-cola` if I chose coca-cola.
Also, how do I add classname to my select?=)

Answer (score -1):

you can use like this, it works

```
<%=select_tag 'brand_name', options_for_select(@brands.collect{ |b| [b.name, b.name] }, params[:dropdownselectvalue])%>
```

on change of select tag send a ajax request with dropdownselect value and reload the same page and set params over the select tag

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696227/how-to-make-the-select-tag-keep-value-of-last-search

Answer (score -1):

What's selected by this control will become available as `params[:brand_name]` after the form is submitted, so you can just reference that as an argument in `select_tag`:

```
<%= select_tag :brand_name,
               options_for_select(@brands.collect{ |b| [b.name, b.name] }),
               params[:brand_name],
               include_blank: 'select brand' %>
```

When nothing has been submitted/selected, `params[:brand_name]` will have a value of `nil`, so nothing will be selected, and the "select brand" row will appear to be selected.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696227/how-to-make-the-select-tag-keep-value-of-last-search