# How to pre-select in options_from_collection_for_select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following form:

```
<%= form_tag users_path, method: :get, id: 'uco' do %>
  <%= select_tag "country", options_from_collection_for_select(ISO3166::Country.countries.sort_by(&:name), 'un_locode', 'name'), :include_blank => true %>
<%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

When I submit the form I end up with:

> www.example.com/users?country=US

I would then like the form to pre-select `params[:country]`.

However I do not know how to attach `params[:country]` into the select_tag. I unsuccessfully tried:

```
<%= select_tag "country", options_from_collection_for_select(ISO3166::Country.countries.sort_by(&:name), 'un_locode', 'name', params[:country]), :include_blank => true %>
```

based off of [this example from the apidock.](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I solved it with this answer:

[How to make the select_tag keep value of last search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696227/how-to-make-the-select-tag-keep-value-of-last-search/10696404#10696404)

`:selected => params[:country]`